# pushing item in mongoid array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a model defined like this :

```
class Foo
  include ::Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :followed_bars, type: Array
  field :favorite_bars, type: Array
end
```

I created a Foo object like this :

```
foo = Foo.new(name: "Test")
foo.save
```

In my DB when I type db.foo.find() I can see the object I just created.
Then, in my application I'm trying to do this :

```
foo = Foo.first
foo.push(:followed_bars, "hello")
```

And every time I'm getting an error : *ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)*

I'm not sure to understand what am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance for help !

Regards.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just found how to do a push on a mongoid array.

In the API documentation they give an example (mongoid 3.x) :

```
Model#push    person.push(:aliases, "007")
```

I'm using mongoid 4.0.0 and they changed the method definition, now we have to use the new syntax so I had to write :

```
foo.push(aliases: "test")
```

Problem solved so.